# Throwing errors inside observer methods in Swift

Tags: swift, validation, error-handling

I'm trying to implement some validation rules inside property observer methods (`didSet` and `willSet`) and I am attempting to use `throw` inside the closure. Here's an illustrative example:

```
enum SomeClassError: ErrorType {
  case NumberNotPositive
}

class SomeClass {
  var PositiveNumber: Int {
    willSet(value) {
      guard value > 0 else {
        throw SomeClassError.NumberNotPositive
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, the compiler complains that `Error is not handled because the enclosing function is not declared 'throws'` and I really don't know where to declare that `didSet` actually `throws`.

Do you know if there is a way to throw errors within property observer methods?

Comment: please include your code

Comment: I don't believe there is. When a property is get or set, the calling code does not expect any errors to be thrown, so the observer must handle all errors itself.

Comment: If you are trying to do validation using a property observer, you could either revert to the old value or reset the property to some sentinel value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function in your property observersdo-try-catch` clause that throws, e.g.

```
enum SomeClassError: ErrorType {
    case NumberNotPositive
}

class SomeClass {
    var positiveNumber: Int {
        willSet {
            do {
                try newValueIsPositive(newValue)
            } catch SomeClassError.NumberNotPositive {
                print("Error: Number not positive")
            } catch {
                print("Error: Unknown error")
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        positiveNumber = 1
    }

    func newValueIsPositive(newValue: Int) throws {
        guard newValue > 0 else {
            throw SomeClassError.NumberNotPositive
        }
    }
}

/* Example */
var a = SomeClass()
a.positiveNumber = 2
a.positiveNumber = -1   // Error: Number not positive
print(a.positiveNumber) // -1
```

Note that I used the `newValue` property accessible by default when using the `willSet` property observer (rather than explicitly defining property name `value` for the value that will be set after `willSet`). Also note that, in your current form, the class property `positiveNumber` still gets assigned `-1` (although an `ErrorType` case is thrown regarding this).

Comment: This code does not stop `positiveNumber` from assuming an invalid value. One possible tweak to achieve that is to turn the `willSet` into `didSet`, call `newValueIsPositive(positiveNumber)` and add at the end of each `catch` block `positiveNumber = oldValue`.

Comment: @catalandres You are right about that, as I did add such a disclaimer just prior to your comment here :) Since the question is about throwing errors in the property observers, I will address only that issue (mentioning, however, that disclaimer). But indeed, it seems as if you can figure that one out now that you've gotten the throwing working!

Comment: What if you do *not* want to cleanly hide the error, but puke it up to the client?

Comment: @CTMacUser I'm note sure I follow; you can perform whatever error handling you'd like in the `catch` blocks. The above example simply prints a message, but you might as well call some delegate method to propagate the error to an appropriate program "location". Also relevant in such a context is e.g. (re-)throwing functions, see the [error handling section in the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) for details.

Comment: @dfri I'm asking if you can omit the `do-catch` setup entirely, mark `willSet` with `throws`, and emit the error to the caller *instead* of completely handling it internally.  I think that's what the OP originally wanted to know.  (I.e. can the original post change it's line to "`willSet(value) throws {`" and be done with it?)

Comment: @CTMacUser I believe this is a (current) limitation of Swift, neither setters/getters or computed properties (as well as property observers and e.g. subscripts) can currently throw, but it's naturally an interest to include throwing for these in future versions of Swift, see e.g. Chris Lattner:s response to [the following Swift evolution thread](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151130/000512.html), as well as [the following evolution proposal draft](https://github.com/brentdax/swift-evolution/blob/throwing-properties-draft/proposals/0000-throwing-properties.md).